# Deciding on SSLRandomSeed values in Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

What rules of thumb should you follow when choosing SSLRandomSeed startup and connect values in Apache?

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrandomseed provides a discussion about various values and methods.